# Add words per topic LDA

Tags: python, windows, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I'm building a LDA in python using Gensim and I'm struggling to increase the number of words printed per topic from the default of 10.  I'd like 20 topics with 30 words each.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

```
# train the LDA model

lda_model = gensim.models.LdaMulticore(bow_corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary, passes=2, workers=2)

# check out the topics

for idx, topic in lda_model.print_topics(-1):
   print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, topic))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options: `show_topics` and `print_topics`.

From the [gensim ldamulticore documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamulticore.html#module-gensim.models.ldamulticore):

`show_topics` (a little bit more customizable alias for `print_topics` that gives prettier output in your case) has the parameter `num_words`  - the number of words you want to display, ranked by significance.

```py
for idx, topic in lda_model.show_topics(idx, num_words=30):
   print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, topic))
```

You can also leave out `idx` - output is unaffected by it. `print_topics` works similarly, but with a default 10 topics to display:

```py
for idx, topic in lda_model2.show_topics(num_topics=20, num_words=30):
   print('Topic: {} \nWords: {}'.format(idx, topic))
```

Comment: Hi Sara, could you provide an explanation as to why this might solve OP's problem? Code only answers are discouraged on stack overflow, especially if the poster does not know what went wrong in the first place!